# Who are the gods and goddesses that appear in Thor: Love and Thunder?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, there were a lot of gods and goddesses shown at Omnipotence City, but several of them are unidentified or not clearly identified in the film. Who are they? Do they have counterparts in the comics or are based on characters from the comics?

Screencaps of the gods and goddesses at Omnipotence City:

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Egyptian (?) goddess] |
| Egyptian (?) goddess - is there a connection to Moon Knight? |
| [image: golden dragon god] |
| golden dragon god - Could it be related to the [Great Protector](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Protector) in *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*? |
| [image: eyeball god] |
| eyeball god |
| [image: Aztec or Mayan god with two African (?) gods] |
| Aztec or Mayan god with two African (?) gods - could the Aztec or Mayan god be related to Namor in *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever*? |
| [image: various gods] |
| various gods |
| [image: masked gods in blue costume] |
| masked gods in blue costume |
| [image: hairy head and feet god] |
| hairy head and feet god |
| [image: various gods] |
| various gods |
| [image: Native American (?) goddess] |
| Native American (?) or Maori (?) goddess |
| [image: Greek (?) goddess; (Athena?)] |
| Greek (?) goddess; (Athena?) - If she's Athena, then this might be a contradiction since in *Eternals* it was implied that [Thena](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thena) (the Eternal) was the Athena of the Greek pantheon. |
| [image: various Greek gods including Zeus] |
| various Greek gods - Aside from Zeus, which god is which? |
| [image: Asian (?) goddess, and hairy head and feet god] |
| Asian (?) goddess, and hairy head and feet god |
| [image: various gods 1] |
| various gods - includes two large gods, one of which is a large Japanese (?) god wearing what appears to be samurai armor; an African (?) god, and a goddess wearing a large headdress |
| [image: various gods 2] |
| various gods - same characters as the screencap above |
| [image: various gods 3] |
| various gods |
| [image: large god] |
| large god |
| [image: Greek (?) god (Dionysus?)] |
| Greek (?) god (Dionysus?) and company |
| [image: goddess wearing a headdress] |
| goddess wearing a headdress |
| [image: celestials (?)] |
| giant gods that look like [Celestials](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Celestials) - Are they actual Celestials or just gods? |
| [image: celestials (?)] |
| giant gods that look like Celestials, the same characters as the screencap above |

Comment: Another of gods are listed in the [imdb credits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10648342/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm), though often without specific names--"Mayan God", "Maori Princess", "Elche Goddess", "Jademurai God", "Aztec God" etc. Minverva is named specifically, she might be the one you have as "Greek Goddess" (Minerva was a Roman goddess, but seen by them as the same as the Greek goddess Athena).

Comment: Also a bunch of recent tweets on [the twitter account "Max Marvel"](https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/with_replies?lang=en) have come up with the likely identities of a bunch of gods, if anyone wants to gather that info together in a post.

Comment: I think the dragon god may have been Shou-Lao, the dragon that the Iron Fist has to defeat in K'un-Lun during his trials.

Comment: Native American (?) - She has a [Moko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C4%81_moko) so is presumably Maori.

Answer (score 7):

> **Bao** - Bao is the God of Dumplings, and a friendly, cheerful god who looks just like an anime dumpling with an emoji face. Unlike some of the other gods in Omnipotence City, he doesn't seem threatened by Thor and his allies, but happy to see them.
>
> **Old Kronan God** - As they're walking to their seats, Korg points out his old Kronan god, who resides on a huge throne reminiscent of the Iron Throne of *Game of Thrones*. In a clever visual joke, the throne is made of scissors–after all, rock beats scissors.
>
> **Bast** - Bast can be spotted in the Omnipotence City scene sitting in front of Jane and Valkyrie. As the Egyptian cat goddess of ancient mythology, in the MCU, she is also the patron goddess of Wakanda. After *Thor: Love and Thunder*, she's set to have a larger role in *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever*.
>
> **Minerva** - The Roman goddess Minerva can also be spotted in the Omnipotence City scene, though she's more regal than some of the other gods. In mythology, Minerva is the goddess of justice, law, and wisdom, and is well-respected among the other gods.
>
> **Artemis** - Yet another Greek deity, Artemis appears among the godly characters in *Thor: Love and Thunder*, though she might be more at home with the Asgardians. Artemis is considered the goddess of the hunt and wild animals. She's also associated with the moon in many cultures.
>
> **Elche Goddess** - An "Elche Goddess" is also listed in the credits for the Omnipotence City scene. She likely takes her name from the Lady of Elche, the name of an ancient bust that depicts a strange pagan goddess with wheels on her head. Some have associated her with Tanit, the patron goddess of the ancient city of Carthage.
>
> **Serpent God (Kukulkan or Quetzalcóatl)** - In the Golden Palace of Omnipotence City, one of the most noticeable gods is a giant, feathered serpent twining around one of the massive pillars that holds up the domed roof. This is undoubtedly Quetzalcóatl  or Kulkulkan, the respective Aztec and Mayan names for the same serpent god. In ancient Mesoamerican belief, he was the god who brought winds, rain, and the sun
>
> **Goddess of the Dead** - In the credits, there is a "Goddess of the Dead" who was also spotted in the scene with the other gods. In the MCU, Hela is the Goddess of Death, so it's unclear which deity this is. However, there are a number of goddesses associated with death across mythology, including the Morrigan, Aita, Persephone, Dea Tacita, Proserpina, Shiva, and others.
>
> **Jademurai God** - A Jademurai God is also briefly seen in the Golden Palace. Played by Kuni Hashimoto, it's unclear if the Jademurai God is based on a real deity, or is a creation for the MCU. However, he appears to be a counterpart of a Japanese god of some sort.
>
> **Fur God** - *The Hobbit*'s Stephen Hunter plays a Fur God in the Golden Palace, though not much is known about him. One of the more niche gods in the movie, he's exactly what he appears - the patron saint of fur.

Source: [*Every God In Thor: Love & Thunder*. Screen Rant.](https://screenrant.com/every-god-in-thor-love-thunder/)

Comment: A couple of tweets from the Max Marvel account [here](https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/status/1546357312440393731) mention that in the comics, the Chinese-inspired god "the Jade Emperor Yu Huang, ruler of Ta-Lo" was always drawn with a Japanese Samurai outfit, so they may have called him "Jademurai God" instead of "Jade Emperor" to avoid people getting annoyed at a Japanese outfit on a character from Chinese mythology. This thread also mentions a few other gods not in your answer, like Amatsu-Mikaboshi and the "Maori Princess" and the likely identity of the Mayan god.

Comment: Also, there is a screenshot of the "Elche Goddess" in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/status/1545819911401967616).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - If that's the case, it is weird that they thought it was more important to make sure the comics super-fans would recognize the clothing that the Jade Emperor wore in the few comics in which he appeared, rather than either keeping his *name* recognizable or just making his appearance more accurate to common portrayals.

Comment: @Adamant could be that it didn't occur to anyone involved with the production that it could be a problem until after the scene had been filmed.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I wonder if Chinese government censorship restrictions have something to do with that.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Note: In this answer, I'm not including gods that have been clearly identified in the film, like Bao, the god of dumplings; and Ninny of the Nonny, the Kronan god.</sup>

##### Aztec god

[image]

This character is listed as "Aztec god" in the credits. It is not mentioned which Aztec god this character is.

> My pitch was ‘why don’t we represent every god by how it is represented in every religion?’ You may have an alabaster or terra cotta god, or an Aztec warrior made of turquoise inlay.

> For the Omnipotence City scene, I did a god costume that had to be all in turquoise, in broken pieces like a mosaic. We actually made a digital print of the inlaid turquoise, with all the nuances in colors, and made a body suit for this actor, and then the makeup artists matched it for his face. His headpiece was a 3D piece with elements to look like solid gold, and then I personally put all the feathers in that.

<sup>- [*Thor: Love and Thunder Costume Designer Mayes C. Rubeo on Dressing Gods & Goddesses* — Motion Picture Association](https://www.motionpictures.org/2022/07/thor-love-and-thunder-costume-designer-mayes-c-rubeo-on-dressing-gods-goddesses/)</sup>

##### Goddess of the Dead

[image]

The character, or the costume, seems to be based on the comic book character, [Amatsu-Mikaboshi](https://www.marvel.com/characters/mikaboshi), a Japanese god.

##### Bast, or Bastet (Wakandan goddess)

[image][image]

> Bastet can be seen directly below Tessa Thompson's Valkyrie and Natalie Portman's Mighty Thor.

<sup>- [*Thor: Love and Thunder Photo Reveals Best Look at Black Panther Easter Egg* — The Direct](https://thedirect.com/article/thor-love-and-thunder-black-panther-easter-egg)</sup>

##### Dionysus

[image]

In the film, he says "Good one, Dad" in response to Zeus' joke. In Greek mythology, Zeus is the father of Dionysus. He is also wearing the typical garb attributed to Dionysus.

##### Lady of Elche

[image: Elche goddess]

> We had a Lady of Elche, which is an anthropological find in the Iberian Peninsula, and we made an orange costume with wheels at the ears.

<sup>- [*Thor: Love and Thunder Costume Designer Mayes C. Rubeo on Dressing Gods & Goddesses* — Motion Picture Association](https://www.motionpictures.org/2022/07/thor-love-and-thunder-costume-designer-mayes-c-rubeo-on-dressing-gods-goddesses/)</sup>

##### Jademurai god

[image]

Based on [The Jade Emperor (Yu Huang)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Yu_Huang_(Earth-616)), from the comics. Despite being from Chinese mythology, this character has always been depicted by Marvel wearing Japanese samurai armor, which probably explains the name change.

##### Mayan god

[image]

> We had a Mayan god, and got the smallest man in Australia and created a costume that was made all of clay like it was a Mayan idol, but then Taika extrapolated that and made him a giant.

<sup>- [*Thor: Love and Thunder Costume Designer Mayes C. Rubeo on Dressing Gods & Goddesses* — Motion Picture Association](https://www.motionpictures.org/2022/07/thor-love-and-thunder-costume-designer-mayes-c-rubeo-on-dressing-gods-goddesses/)</sup>

##### Minerva

[image]

In the credits, this character is named as Minerva (the Roman goddess), rather than Athena (the Greek goddess), probably to avoid contradicting *Eternals*, where it was implied that [Thena](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thena) (the Eternal) was the Athena of the Greek pantheon.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the possible Egyptian goddess is Isis because if I recall, I heard “Goddess of Magic” when it panned over her.

[image]